# Paste multiple cells into a single cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code several buttons to help out with archiving information into neat data.
But the value spreads over several rows.

I need it to go into a single cell.
Also would be swell if i could clear the copied data of all formatting and use the paste workbook as format "giver"

I am very new to Coding and mostly read up and copy pasted information. Nothing of value tried

```
Sheet4.Range("D25", Workbooks("Underlag.xlsm").Worksheets("EU").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Copy Workbooks("Arkiv.xlsm").Worksheets("EU").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
```

Expected result is to have to copied data go into a single cell,
actual result is that it spreads over rows ruining data from other buttons.

Comment: Is that your actual code? With `Destination` on a new line, without the previous line ending with `_`?

Comment: Did not know it would be a full line, preview tricked me. Edited it to normal.

Comment: You are specifically copying a range of cells. If you want to only take up one cell in the destination, copy one cell to begin with.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to create a loop which checks row for row after data and adds it into earlier question?
something like
If cell 1 not empty
go to cell 2
if cell 2 not empty

Cell 1 & Cell 2 = Sheet.cell 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this :

```
Sub test_paste()

    Dim allData As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim pasteRng As Range

    Set rng = Sheet4.Range("D25", Workbooks("Underlag.xlsm").Worksheets("EU").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
    Set pasteRng = Workbooks("Arkiv.xlsm").Worksheets("EU").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            allData = allData & cell & " "
        End If
    Next

    pasteRng = allData

End Sub
```

It appends the values of each individual cells in the original range into a string, then puts that string in the chosen cell.
note: I tried this in only one sheet, not across different workbook